# Welcome in room number 2

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Congrats! You've just escaped from [this room.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/a-strange-array)

Still, it seems you are not free yet. You are in another room, again, a numeric pad next to a door with this message

> Enter passcode: _ _ _ _ _ _ 
>   Remaining tries: 1

You are seeing this riddle on a screen on the wall, a mouse allow you to interract with the site. *Take this Inception!*

[image: code: 236851][image: code: 783185][image: flash me please][image: code: 258274][image: code: 201168][image: code: 123966]

Now, find the code to escape the room !

hint:

> Hagfy found some interesting hidden words in the previous room. Maybe the pictures are related to these :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is how to read @PunPun1000's finding:

> ```
> G|----|----||
> D|----|----||
> A|---5|-0-0||
> E|100-|3-1-||
> ```
>
> Each number on a bass tab is a half-tone higher than the note on the line, so for A:
> 0 = A
> 1 = A#
> 2 = B
> 3 = C
> 4 = C#
> 5 = D
>
> End result seems (to me) to be **FEED|GAFA**
>
> **NOTE** The **|** is just the bar-line, and does not seem to be a logical operator.  Apologies for the confusion.

@Zimonze has an answer for the second half of this finding:

> GAFA is an abbreviation for the 4 tech giants (Google, Apple, Facebook, Amazon)

The final answer might just be

> the apple's code (258274), as it's he only one that is explicitly part of GAFA and also related to 'feed'ing.

If not, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: yep, that was the message to find here :)

Comment: (Usually A# is written Bb... ;) )

Comment: @IanMacDonald True, but in this case I was moving up the scale, so I went with incrementally raised steps (sharps), which was not meant to diminish the importance of the flats.  =)

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer :)

Answer (score 5):

> Checking the edit page I found that each picture has a code on it, like the code for the plate is  236851. I noticed that the QR picture did not have a code for it and there was a little box beside it that said "flash me please". So, I am guessing that there is a 6-digit code embedded in the image that will lead to the answer. 
>  [image: here]

Comment: you are on the right tracks, think you should give that qr-code a shot :)

Comment: I have no Idea on how to find hidden thing in images... But I'll try :D

Comment: I added some information about the QR code in my answer if you wanna check it out

Comment: Really helpful definite +1

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer to the QR code

> The QR code hides the message `smth hides in prev src`.  Looking at the previous puzzle linked, we can see that there was a change an hour ago which added the following hidden message
>  `hey fella, welcome back, I would like to tell you you should always get your informations from multiple sources, but maybe you also want to play, here's a bass tab, hope you like it: 
>
> G|----|----||
> D|----|----||
> A|---5|-0-0||
> E|100-|3-1-||`
>  The message is hidden in a php comment if that matters

Comment: hope you like bass guitar :)

Comment: @Flying_whale I hope someone more knowledgeable about bass guitars likes the info.  It doesn't mean a whole ton to me without some research.

Answer (score 2):

> Using "Search Google for image" on all the images, all of them except the QR code and soccer ball produced results for French sites. This could be connected to the French flag in the previous room (Clue for AZERTY).
>
>  Also, regarding the FEED|GAFA, GAFA is an abbreviation for the 4 tech giants (Google, Apple, Facebook, Amazon). This could hint to "feeding" them by using their services, similar to the image search I have done.

Comment: you are right for *GAFA*

Comment: so the french was a little bit of a stretch, wasn't it.

Comment: yep, everything that has to be found in first room was only in the hidden part ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @hagfy's findings:

> FEED|GAFA almost looks like a bitwise OR operation in hex. The only issue is the "G", which isn't part of the hex alphabet. If we interpret "G" as a "10" in hex, we instead get:
>
>  `0xFEED | 0x10AFA = 130815`
>  
>  which is six digits. The only other way to look at this message, assuming I'm on the right track with the bitwise OR, would be using a different base -- but base 17 gives a 5-digit number, and a base less than 16 doesn't make sense.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment; try answering/asking questions to gain reputation first

Comment: the | is not the logic OR, it is only a bar-line

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tris response, wouldnt it be

> 133607? adding both hex 0xFEED and 0x10AFA to decimal

Comment: the | is only a bar-line, not the OR operator here :)

Comment: Seems like on you images, the first one goes to "feed", apple to apple, soccer ball to "facebook" and last pic nique image goes to amazon, so I asume beer code is "google" and the qr code is the bar-line(qr is formed by bar-lines)? or maybe beer is bar-line and qr code is google? stuck on there